# Merging overlapping/intersecting string vectors

Tags: optimization, performance, r, vectorization

I am trying to merge overlapping/intersecting sets given as a list of string vectors below in R (my actual data set has thousands of such sets). The overlap/intersection is based on the `SDxyz:` string and not the string after the ":".

```
d <- list(
  c("SD1:LUSH", "SD44:CANCEL", "SD384:FR563", "SD32:TRUMPET"), 
  c("SD23:SWITCH", "SD1:LUSH", "SD567:TREK"),
  c("SD42:CRAYON", "SD345:FOX", "SD183:WIRE"),
  c("SD345:HOLE", "SD340:DUST", "SD387:ROLL"),
  c("SD455:TOMATO", "SD39:MATURE"),
  c("SD12:PAINTING", "SD315:MONEY31", "SD387:SPRING"),
  c("SD32:TRUMPET", "SD1:FIELD"))
```

The final desired out put is as follows.

```
out <-  list (
        c("SD1:LUSH", "SD1:FIELD", "SD23:SWITCH", "SD32:TRUMPET", "SD44:CANCEL", "SD384:FR563",  "SD567:TREK") ,
        c("SD12:PAINTING", "SD42:CRAYON", "SD183:WIRE", "SD340:DUST", "SD345:FOX", "SD345:HOLE", "SD315:MONEY31", "SD387:SPRING", "SD387:ROLL"),
        c("SD455:TOMATO", "SD39:MATURE"))
```

This is the code I could come up with using `data.table` package.

```
### Create a data.table Bloc with one column with original groups and the other with the separated ids
d <- list( c("SD1:LUSH", "SD44:CANCEL", "SD384:FR563", "SD32:TRUMPET"), c("SD23:SWITCH", "SD1:LUSH", "SD567:TREK"), c("SD42:CRAYON", "SD345:FOX", "SD183:WIRE"), c("SD345:HOLE", "SD340:DUST", "SD387:ROLL"), c("SD455:TOMATO", "SD39:MATURE"), c("SD12:PAINTING", "SD315:MONEY31", "SD387:SPRING"),  c("SD32:TRUMPET", "SD1:FIELD"))
d2 <-  lapply(d, function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), "[", 1))

d <- lapply(d, paste0, collapse=", ")
d2 <- lapply(d2, paste0, collapse=", ")

d <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(lapply(d, paste0, collapse=", ")))
d2 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(lapply(d2, paste0, collapse=", ")))

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(d,d2))
colnames(d) <- c("sdw", "sd")
d$sd <- as.character(d$sd)
d$sdw <- as.character(d$sdw)

require(data.table)
Bloc <- data.table( d , key = "sd" )

### Fetch all the ids along with the corresponding data in Bloc

Bloc <- Bloc[ , list( ID = unlist( strsplit( sd , "," ) ) ) , by = list(sdw, sd) ]
Bloc$ID <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", Bloc$ID)
Bloc <- data.table( Bloc , key = "ID" )


### Loop to merge the vectors having ids intersecting between them

Bloc <- as.data.frame(Bloc)
M <- nrow(Bloc)
#create blankd data.frame
G <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
G[,1:3] <- as.character(G[,1:3])
#G <- data.frame(sdw=character(), sd=character(), ID= character())
colnames(G) <- c("sdw", "sd", "ID")
N <- M
mch <- as.data.frame(Bloc)
#Loop to sequentially fill data.frame
for (i in 1:M) {
  # test if ID already in previous groups
  if(Bloc[i,"ID"] %in% G$ID == FALSE) { 
    # convert element to vector to check for intersect
    tm <- strsplit(x=Bloc[i, "sd"], split=", ")
    mch$t <- numeric(length=M)
  }
  for (j in 1:N){
    #if intersect exists apply code as 1 mch$t column
    ff <- strsplit(x=mch[j, "sd"], split=", ")[[1]]
    dd <- intersect (tm[[1]], ff)
    if (identical(dd, character(0))== FALSE) mch[j,"t"] = 1
  }
  submch <- subset(mch, t == 1 )
  ID <- submch$ID
  Group1 <- sort((unlist(strsplit(paste0(submch$sdw, collapse=","), ","))))
  Group1 <- unique(gsub(" ","", Group1))
  sdw <- rep(paste0(Group1, collapse=", "), nrow(submch))
  Group2 <- sort((unlist(strsplit(paste0(submch$sd, collapse=","), ","))))
  Group2 <- unique(gsub(" ","", Group2))
  sd <- rep(paste0(Group2, collapse=", "), nrow(submch))
  G1 <- cbind(sdw, sd, ID)
  G1 <- unique(G1)
  G <- rbind(G, G1)
  mch$t <- NULL
}

G <- unique(G)
G2 <- data.table(G, key="ID")
G2 <- G2[, list(sdw = paste0(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(sdw, split=", ")))), collapse=", "), 
                sd = paste0(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(sd, split=", ")))), collapse=", "))  , by = "ID"]
G2 <- data.table( G2, key=c("sd", "sdw"))
G2 <- unique(G2)

### Get the output as data.table

Bloc <- G2[-1,]
Bloc$ID <- NULL

### Repeat the above loop until no more intersects are left

repeat
{
  N1 <- nrow(Bloc)
  Bloc <- Bloc[ , list( ID = unlist( strsplit( sd , "," ) ) ) , by = list(sdw, sd) ]
  Bloc$ID <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", Bloc$ID)
  Bloc <- data.table( Bloc , key = "ID" )

  Bloc <- as.data.frame(Bloc)
  M <- nrow(Bloc)
  #create blankd data.frame
  G <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  G[,1:3] <- as.character(G[,1:3])
  #G <- data.frame(sdw=character(), sd=character(), ID= character())
  colnames(G) <- c("sdw", "sd", "ID")
  N <- M
  mch <- as.data.frame(Bloc)
  #Loop to sequentially fill data.frame
  for (i in 1:M) {
    # test if ID already in previous groups
    if(Bloc[i,"ID"] %in% G$ID == FALSE) { 
      # convert element to vector to check for intersect
      tm <- strsplit(x=Bloc[i, "sd"], split=", ")

      mch$t <- numeric(length=M)
    }
    for (j in 1:N){
      #check if intersect exists and code accordingly
      ff <- strsplit(x=mch[j, "sd"], split=", ")[[1]]
      dd <- intersect (tm[[1]], ff)
      if (identical(dd, character(0))== FALSE) mch[j,"t"] = 1
    }
    submch <- subset(mch, t == 1 )
    ID <- submch$ID
    Group1 <- sort((unlist(strsplit(paste0(submch$sdw, collapse=","), ","))))
    Group1 <- unique(gsub(" ","", Group1))
    sdw <- rep(paste0(Group1, collapse=", "), nrow(submch))
    Group2 <- sort((unlist(strsplit(paste0(submch$sd, collapse=","), ","))))
    Group2 <- unique(gsub(" ","", Group2))
    sd <- rep(paste0(Group2, collapse=", "), nrow(submch))
    G1 <- cbind(sdw, sd, ID)
    G1 <- unique(G1)
    G <- rbind(G, G1)
    mch$t <- NULL
  }

  G <- unique(G)
  G2 <- data.table(G, key="ID")

  G2 <- G2[, list(sdw = paste0(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(sdw, split=", ")))), collapse=", "), 
                  sd = paste0(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(sd, split=", ")))), collapse=", "))  , by = "ID"]
  G2 <- data.table( G2, key=c("sd", "sdw"))
  G2 <- unique(G2)
  Bloc <- G2[-1,]
  Bloc$ID <- NULL
  N2 <- nrow(Bloc)  
  if (N1 == N2)
    break
}

### Output

Bloc$sdw
```

I know it is ugly. Is there any way to vectorize and speed up the code. Right now it works, but is painfully slow for large number of sets.

Comment: I really don't get what you're trying to do here. The `out` vector looks like a union of all the vectors without duplicates, but instead of a simple vector of N string elements, it's a vector of 3 strings with comma separated values. Why should there be 3 elements in the output?

Comment: @janos I want to get the union of all the intersecting/overlapping vectors based on the SDxyz strings. The above code searches if there is any overlap between vectors. If there is an overlap,  the respective strings are merged.

Comment: @janos For greater clarity I have changed the desired output `out` to a list. `d[[1]]`, `d[[2]]` and `d[[7]]` have overlaps among them, so they are merged to `out[[1]]`. Similarly `d[[3]]` ,`d[[4]]` and `d[[6]]` have been merged to `out[[2]]`. `d[[5]]` doesn't have any overlaps with other sets, so it remains as such in `out[[3]]`.

Comment: Isn't `SD315:MONEY31` missing at the `out[[2]]`?

Comment: @djhurio That is right. Good catch. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `data.table` syntax, you can shorten and speed up your code a lot. The following code should get the same result as you got (except for the order).

```
### Create a data.table Bloc with one column with original groups and the other with the separated ids
d <- list(c("SD1:LUSH", "SD44:CANCEL", "SD384:FR563", "SD32:TRUMPET"), 
          c("SD23:SWITCH", "SD1:LUSH", "SD567:TREK"), 
          c("SD42:CRAYON", "SD345:FOX", "SD183:WIRE"), 
          c("SD345:HOLE", "SD340:DUST", "SD387:ROLL"), 
          c("SD455:TOMATO", "SD39:MATURE"), 
          c("SD12:PAINTING", "SD315:MONEY31", "SD387:SPRING"),  
          c("SD32:TRUMPET", "SD1:FIELD"))
# using substr instead of 2 loops (only works if all elements really have a :)
d2 <- lapply(d, function(x) substr(x, 1,  regexpr(":", x)-1))
# using sapply 
# using stringsAsFactors = FALSE to avoid later conversion
d <- as.data.frame(sapply(d, paste0, collapse=", "), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
d2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(d2, paste0, collapse=", "), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# binding
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(d,d2))
colnames(d) <- c("sdw", "sd")
#
require(data.table)
Bloc <- data.table(d , key = "sd")
### Fetch all the ids along with the corresponding data in Bloc
Bloc <- Bloc[ , list( ID = unlist( strsplit( sd , "," ) ) ) , by = list(sdw, sd) ]
## use := to avoid copying
Bloc[, ID := gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", Bloc$ID)]
# use setkey
setkey(Bloc, "ID")
# grouping
Bloc[, group:=.GRP, by = sdw]
# while there are 'wrong' groups
while (any(Bloc[, group>min(group), by = ID][, V1], 
           Bloc[, group>min(group), by = sdw][, V1])){
  # adjust grouping
  Bloc[, group:=min(group), by = ID]
  Bloc[, group:=min(group), by = sdw]
}
# 
res <- Bloc[, unique(unlist(strsplit(unique(sdw), ", "))), by=group]
# splitting to get the list comparable to out
split(res$V1, res$group)
```